# How to orient a Scourge of War unit?

Tags: scourge-of-war

I've been starting Scourge of War: Waterloo because I want to play Napoleonics. However I'm finding a game mechanic extremely difficult.

When you want to move a unit and change its facing, you right click the destination point, which shows a green line with a triangle which shows the unit's destination and facing. You are supposed to use the mouse to rotate the line while the right button is down in order to get the facing you want. However even at highest resolution (1980px - it's an old game) the line and triangle are extremely difficult to see, and the orientation difficult to control. Getting it wrong can end up with your units facing away from the enemy, which is usually fatal.

Is there another way of doing this, or some kind of hint or setting to get round this problem?